# Mock rest API call using mockjax

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data, qunit, mockjax

I am using ember-cli to develop an ember application and ember-data with restful API calls to a rails backend.

Also using qunit for testing purpose. (https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax for mocking AJAX request)

Here am facing issue while mocking the AJAX requests

```
import Ember from "ember";
import DS from "ember-data";
import { test, moduleFor } from 'ember-qunit';
import startApp from '../../helpers/start-app';
var App;

module('Integration Test', {
  setup: function() {
    App = startApp();
    Ember.$.mockjax({
      url: '/api/v1/offers/1',
      type: 'GET',
      responseText: {
        offers: [{
          id: 1,
          state: 'draft'
        }]
      }
    });
  },

  teardown: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.destroy);
  }
});

test('small test', function () {
  console.log("in")
  $.get('/api/v1/offers/1')
  console.log($.mockjax.mockedAjaxCalls().length);
  console.log("start")

  visit('/offers/1').then(function(){
    equal($('p.item_count').text(), "Offer Items(0)");
  });
  console.log($.mockjax.mockedAjaxCalls().length);
});
```

On console it produces output as

```
in
MOCK GET: /api/v1/offers 
Object {url: "/api/v1/offers", type: "get", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true…}
start
1 
1
```

Here the API is called using restful adapter, but not using the mocked AJAX call.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You've only mocked one of those URLs, did you mock the `/offers/1` URL somewhere else? If not, you need to add both to Mockjax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While making a call using mockjax. We need to make sure following things:

- Adaptera/application.js should have

  ```
  if(window.app.environment === "test") {
    Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({ namespace: "ifany" });
  }
  ```
- With Ember-Cli `ember-data-factory-guy` is a good option to use and that has support for `mockAjax` as well
- With FactoryGuy using `FactoryGuy.buildList("user", 9)` you can get a json response easilyand api call will work as well

  ```
  $.mockjax({
    url: '/api/v1/offers/1',
    type: 'GET',
    responseText: {
    offers: Factory.buildList("offer",9)
    }
  });
  ```
- Also make sure you run the app in test mode

  ```
  ember server -environment=test
  ```

Comment: Thanks.. Here instead of using mockjax, now I am switching to api-stub provided by ember-cli